# How to implement a filter extracting range custom entity

Tags: dialogflow-es

I would like to train a Dialogflow agent which will be able to extract specific filter from user's input. For example, if the user inputs something like "the users between age 18 and 25". the agent will be able to extract the filter parameter and output something like

```
"parameters": {
      "age-range": {
        "startAge": 18,
        "endAge": "25
      }
```

From what I know, the custom entities only support key value mapping such as "colour: "blue" but how do I implement an entity that extract a particular range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that using a [Composite Entity](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-options#comp) is best for something like this, since people could express this range in a number of ways. For example, users could say things such as:

- users between age 18 and 25
- users younger than 18
- users who are at least 18, but younger than 25
- any user who is at least 18 years old
- users aged 18 through 25

You may want to add all of these as [training phrases](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-training-phrases) with up to two [parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-actions-parameters#params) of type `@sys.number`.